# How to save/export boundary edge of a mesh in meshlab

Tags: edges, boundary, meshlab

I have a mesh and I would like to save the boundary edge result in a file (as 3D wires). Is there a way to do it? In the picture below, it is green edges. Thanks
[exemple of boundary edges in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czfoj.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same and did the following:

1. Select all the mesh faces
2. Go to **Filter > Quality Measure and Computations > Create Selection Perimeter Polyline**

Hope that works for you too.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks